Getting ORA-03106: Fatal Two-Task Communication protocol error in NodeJS calling a procedure
Currently, I'm using NodeJS/Typescript and node-oracledb (v5.5.0) to connect to an oracle database to run some queries. I'm using an oracle connection pool to get the connections. What I've been experiencing lately is an issue regarding Fatal Two-Task Communication protocol error whenever I'm calling a procedure/package. The only "fix" I have found is to refactor the query and this will somehow start working but it's a temporary solution. As an example:
let connection;

try {
  connection = await oracledb.getConnection();
  
  const query1 = `BEGIN GET_DETAILS_PKG.fetch_details(:p_id, :p_result); END;`; // This does NOT work and causes error
  
 // query2 will successfully run without any issues
 const query2 = `BEGIN
 GET_DETAILS_PKG.fetch_details(
 :p_id,
 :p_result);
 END;`
 
 const binds = { 
   p_id: { dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, type: oracledb.NUMBER, val: req.body.id },
   p_result: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CLOB }
 };

  const result = await connection.execute(query2, binds, { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT });
catch (error) {
  logger.error(`Error in getting details: ${error}`);
} finally {
  if (connection) {
    await connection.close();
  }
}



For this example, the variable/query named as query2 will run fine (for some time at least) while query1 will cause the Fatal Two-Task Communication protocol error. Any idea why this happens, or areas I should look to see what might be causing it? Because even though query2 might work for now, it might later cause the error, and then switching to query1 will again work.
Changing the query to a block format style

For a start, 5.5 is badly out of date, so you should upgrade.  Then, check any database or Oracle Client library logs (you might need to enable these).  Check whether you have a firewall killing "idle" connections that haven't had any network traffic on for a while.
